# Ansible - set_fact syntax issue

Tags: ansible

In the below playbook, can someone please tell me what is wrong with the syntax of the final set_fact statement. If i explicitly specify the hostname R9 (as per the first set_fact), then it works without issue. But if I assign a variable to have a value of R9, and then use this in the final set_fact statement, I get the error shown below. Argh.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ansible_network_os: ios
    ansible_connection: network_cli

  tasks:
   - ios_command:  
         commands: show ip arp
     register: results

   - set_fact:
        some_var: "{{ hostvars['R9'].results }}"

   - set_fact:
       hostname: "R9"

   - set_fact:
        another_var: "{{ hostvars['{{hostname}}'].results }}"

   - debug:
       var=some_var

   - debug:
       var=another_var
```

Error:

```
fatal: [R7]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['{{hostname}}']" is undefined
  
    The error appears to be in '/root/ansible/Rapid/testsetfact.yml': line 20, column 6, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
       - set_fact:
         ^ here
fatal: [R9]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['{{hostname}}']" is undefined
  
    The error appears to be in '/root/ansible/Rapid/testsetfact.yml': line 20, column 6, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
       - set_fact:
         ^ here
```

Comment: Try `hostvars[ {{hostname}} ]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the line to this :   

 - set_fact:
        another_var: "{{ hostvars[ {{hostname}} ].results }}"

But I get this error now: 

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [R9]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'template error while templating string: expected token '':'', got ''}''. String: {{ hostvars[ {{hostname}} ].results }}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `inventory_hostname` for your purpose:

```
  - set_fact:
      another_var: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].results }}"
```

Comment: Much thanks. This helped. Clearly my problem was placing the variable **hostname** inside the double braces and the single quotes. Once I removed those, it worked.